# use nodejs variable from post request

Tags: node.js

hey im trying to get some object in my nodejs by post request 
so when i send the post request the req.body.parm will take the variable its self not json or string

there is the examp

```
const variable = Markup.inlineKeyboard([[Markup.callbackButton('', 'like')]])
app.post('/sendMessage', (req,res)=>{

// console.log(req.body);
// res.status(200).send('OK')

if(!req.body.user_id)
{
    return res.status(402).send({
        message: "UserId cannot be empty"
    });
}

Bot.sendMessage(parseInt(req.body.user_id),req.body.message,req.body.variable);
res.status(200).send({message:'Message has been sent to ' + req.body.user_id});
```

});

the request im sending is:

```
{"user_id":"815779314","message":"its a TEST","variable":"variable"}
```

so what i want to get at req.body.variable the const variable its self how can i do that ?

Comment: You want const variable value in response?

Comment: i have solve that with `eval()` thank you